# Kworker consumes 100% of CPU

Tags: nvidia

`kworker` process is consuming 100% of my CPU.
It doesn't happen always but, when it starts consuming 100% of the CPU, there is no way to reduce its load.

I'm working on a NVIDIA Jetson TX2 and I have a CAN bus and a Lidar connected via ethernet. I suppose it has something to do with these two hardware connections as they work with interrupts, but I still can't figure out how to prevent this from happening.

I know this is a well known bug, but every solution i found seems to pass via ACPI ([this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398520/kworker-consumes-high-cpu-for-external-hard-drive/460696#460696), for example), but when I look in `/sys/firmware` I have no ACPI folder. 
I've also tried [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/high-cpu-usage-by-kworker-4175563563/) solution. At first it seemed that it was working, but it just worked for a little longer and then the `kworker` appeared again.

Can anyone provide any advice to solve this issue?